# Can I know the hwnd value of the Link Info button of Hiearchy?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

In max script, I want to make the Link Info button on the Hiarchy panel pressed.
I used the getchildhwnd function etc, but I couldn't find the hwnd value. Is there a way to know the hwnd value of the link info button, or to make the link info button pressed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The Hierarchy Panel and its buttons are Qt-based even though the rollouts it contains are still Win32.  You can discover this yourself with a development tool like Spy++ that ships with Visual Studio.  There is no built-in meaningful access to Qt functionality via MAXScript.

Even if you were hitting this as a C++ plugin and attempting to force signals into the Qt button, I think you'd be asking for a world of pain.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve, perhaps you're thinking about it backwards.

The rollouts provided in the Link Info section affect node Transform Lock and Inheritance flags.  If your goal is to modify these, consider using the following MAXScript functions instead:

- `getTransformLockFlags`
- `setTransformLockFlags`
- `getInheritanceFlags`
- `setInheritanceFlags`